# Remove wall mounted electric heaters and switch to portable?

Tags: heating, building-regulations, electric-heat

I would like to remove three wall mounted electric heaters from the rooms in our flat.

The flat is about 11 years old and is fairly efficient:

- Two of the heaters (bedroom and hallway) have never been used in the six years that we've lived here.
- The heater in our main living space is used a handful of times a year, but it would be more efficient and useful to switch to a portable heating device.

I'm not clear on the building regulations. Is there a minimum requirement for fixed / built-in heating devices?

EDIT: Should have mentioned that we are in the UK!

Comment: If "building regulations" is anything close to "you rent this flat", you may have to get the landlord's and city's permissions and permits for this. Some jurisdictions don't allow for tenants to modify the services in the rental. If you own the flat, the local jurisdiction should be able to say how much heating service your flat should need.

Comment: @Triplefault can you give me some hints as to how to find out who the local jurisdiction is - would this be the local council? We own the flat.

Comment: Your question need to be answered on the local level.  In my location heat and AC is not required to get a certificate of occupancy. However one cannot get insurance or financing on a home without some form of permanent AC.

Comment: The only benefit portable has over mounted is the ease of moving it.  They will use as much power as the mounted ones for the same heat.  Removing the heaters will also need wall repair and probably painting.  The colour of paint behind the heaters will not be the same as the rest of the wall now, mainly do to different fading.

Comment: "Local council" Could be. Whatever your local government is, they should be able to guide you to the local jurisdiction over construction codes.

Comment: @RMDman  I guess they are right about location being important.  I got maybe 20 hours on my AC in the last 20 plus years.  Heat is on/needed almost six/seven months of each year.

Comment: @crip659, opposite here....AC needed 10 months out of the year. Heat maybe 10 days.

Comment: I should have said that we're in the UK - no requirements for AC and the weather is fairly mild, so I'm not sure whether or not there would be minimum heating requirements.

Comment: There likely are minimum heating requirements. For one thing, nobody wants pipes to freeze.

Comment: @songololo  Having a heat source and AC is better to have and not use, than not having and needed.  UK does get weather extremes as most other places every so often.  We do hear about the UK heatwaves even here across the pond.  And the thames has frozen up.

Comment: Is your flat heated only by baseboards, or is there another heating source, such as a heatpump?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the only heating source is the wall mounted electric radiators